# get command executed result from docker container

Tags: bash, docker

anyway for me to know when command is finished inside docker container? I have created a docker container and able to send command from my local into docker container by docker exec
so far in my bash script I am using sleep to wait until "cd root: npm install" command finished inside docker container. If I do not have sleep, done is printed out right away after npm install is sent into docker container. How can I remove sleep so done is printed out only after `npm install` is finished inside docker container?

`docker exec -d <docker container name> bash -c "cd root;npm install"
sleep 100
echo "done"`

Comment: Never install software into a running Docker container: it will be lost as soon as the container exits.  If you're trying to run commands like `npm install` then a Dockerfile is better; see the official Docker tutorial on [building and running custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/).

Answer (score 1):

Don't background the command if you want to keep it running in the foreground (the `-d` flag):

```
docker exec <docker container name> bash -c "cd root;npm install"
echo "done"
```

Answer (score 0):

Run it as background process `&` and then `wait` for it:

```
docker exec -d <docker container name> bash -c "cd root;npm install" &
wait
echo "done"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you omit the `-d` (detach) the `docker exec` will return only after completion (and not immediately), so no `wait` will be needed.